# Как быстро удалить и очистить 500к+ файлов в linux?

Tags: linux

Есть интересная задача:
Есть папка в котором скопилось 500000 файлов логов.

1. Нужно удалить файлы, которые не используются программой.
2. Нужно очистить файлы, которые используется программой.

Я попробовал так:

```bash
for i in $LOGS1; do
 if [[ -f $i ]]; then
  /sbin/fuser -s $i
  if [[ $? -eq 1 ]]; then
   #echo "Удаляем $i $?"
   /bin/rm -f $i
  else
   #echo "Очищаем $i $?"
   > $i
  fi
 fi
done
```

Но работает крайне медленно, может выполнять несколько дней, есть ли предложения как можно выполнить эту задачу быстрее?
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: Возможно я сейчас чушь напишу, но лично я бы использовал для этих целей nodejs, потому что А - сам язык в разы быстрее чем баш, Б - асинхронные запросы к файловой системе.

Comment: rm -dfr $i может быстрее отработать, если именно баш нужен

Comment: да можно даже не в баше, просто хотел узнать как "это" выполнить быстрее.

Comment: rm -dfr $i не подойдёт это файлы, а не папки и не надо рекурсию, все файлы в одной папке, просто папка с 500к+ логами, с разными именами

Comment: @BadmaevSaykhan а вы гуглили эту тему? на хабре вот например есть статья: https://habrahabr.ru/post/157613

Comment: @BeastWinterwolf гуглил, ничего внятного не нашёл, мне ведь надо очистить зёрна от плевел сначала, и лишь потом удалять, а ls -f | xargs rm, удаляет отлично, но диск всё равно полный

Comment: Учимся писать на shell, да? `man find`. Программа поддерживает SIGSTOP / SIGCONT? Если да и если это позволительно, то алгоритм примерно таков: 1) тормозим программу. 2) через */proc/<PID>/fd/* узнаём текущие открытые файлы (даже, если они удалены!), 3) запускаем `find` так, чтобы собрать все файлы, 4) когда списки в памяти можно делать что требуется, 5) запускаем программу с остановленного места.